# Can Converter know about parent control?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a `Prism` Core MVVM application, which reuses some views, like **CustomerView**. Initially, CustomerView is shown as a 'tile' in the **MainWindowView**. When user clicks on it - new instance of that CustomerView is opened in a new `Window`, using my WindowService. CustomerView has a menu. What I want: if CustomerView is displayed in MainWindowView's 'tile' - menu should be hidden; if in another distinct `Window` - menu should be visible. Currently, I have this done with code-behind. Is it possible to have a `Converter`, which could figure if CustomerView is a part of MainWindowView, or of some other `Window`?

Comment: Prism works with regions not with windows. Therefore you can check what views are located inside a certain region.

Comment: @Gleb - it doesn't help me, I need it the other way round - converter, used in a view, to figure inside what region it is hosted

Comment: I'd reuse one level down, create a view without menu for the main window and one view with menu for the detail view with menu, both using a third view as common content. All three can also share the same view model. I suppose, sooner or later, the tile will differ from the detail view in more than just the presence of the menu, anyway, and you'll be able to reduce the common content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the `CustomerView` itself and use a helper method that tries to find a parent `MainWindowView` in the visual tree:

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
MainWindowView parent = FindParent<MainWindowView>(customerView);
if (parent != null)
    //MainWindowView found...
```

Comment: Well, it should work generally, but I didn't mention that my CustomerView resides in a ContentControl (Prism region) and is shown using Prism's regionManager.RequestNavigate method. In this case FindParent<MainWindowView>(customerView) always returns null, no matter what Type I specify for it

Comment: seems to work tho, if I use LogicalTreeHelper instead of VisualTreeHelper in FindParent

Comment: @AlexeyTitov: Where does that leave your question? Is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes, its solved - if I use LogicalTreeHelper instead of VisualTreeHelper in your FindParent method